# git clone https://github.com/pribot/rbx1.git

Tags: ros, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read about the book ros_by_example_indigo_volume_1 , first time i tap

```
git clone https://github.com/pribot/rbx1.git
```

it print

```
Username for 'https://github.com'
```

im sure it not talking about 'my own' username.

second i tap

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git
```

it worked , but when i tap

```
git checkout indigo-devel
```

it print:

```
error: pathspec 'indigo-devel' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I download the zip form web page and unzip it to my `~/catkin_ws/src` and try to `catkin_make`, nothing happen.
how can i do next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221309/git-clone-https://github.com/pribot/rbx1.git/) by [RL90](https://answers.ros.org/users/25139/rl90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/pribot/rbx1.git
> ```

It is indeed `pirobot/rbx1.git`, not `pribot`.

> ```
> git checkout indigo-devel
> ```

This works for me, but only if I clone `pirobot/rbx1.git`. I don't know whether the `pribot/rbx1.git` repository contains such a branch.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0